# MVC Web API 5 Upgrade for CORS support

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to use CORS support with Web API, and have installed RC1. I have wasted so much time trying to get CORS to work correctly. Anyhow I have enabled Nightly builds with no avail. I keep getting the following issue and cannot find a solution anywhere on the net. Do you need 2013 VS to play with MVC 5 or install anything new?

```
Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.Hosting.IHostPrincipalService' from assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

This is my packages file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="3.0.0-ci1043" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.1.0-alpha1-131016" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.0.0-rc1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core" version="1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDB" version="1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.0.0-rc1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.0.0-rc1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.1.0-alpha1-131016" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.1.0-alpha1-131016" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.1.0-alpha1-131016" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.0.0-rc1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.0.0-rc1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.0.0-rc1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NodaTime" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: did you had a look here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api?

Comment: Ya thats what initially led me down this path. You cannot install that specific package because it fails when making an options pre-flight request with basic-auth. It is meant to be fixed in the Nightly build, but when upgrading to the nightly build, everything else seems to break, hence my post. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I am seeing what appears to be the same issue in Visual Studio 2013, but when trying to use the System.Web.Mvc project. In my case, it is warning that "strong name validation failed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have VS 2013 to use MVC 5 / Web API 2. You can use it with VS 2012.

Try [updating all your packages](http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20All%20Packages) to RTM versions and also check the following [article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) on upgrading to MVC 5 and Web API 2.

To use MVC 5 and Web API 2 with VS 2012 you need to install the [ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

There are also other ways of enabling CORS on the server-side, other than using the ASP.NET CORS Nuget package.  You can add the CORS headers to the response manually (e.g. by writing a custom [Web API MessageHandler](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers), or using some other code mechanism to add a header to the response), or you can add headers using the [web.config](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html):

Using the CORS Nuget package is probably the recommended approach (once the 5.1+ version is actually released), but it is not the only way.

I've gotten these alternative methods to work in VS2012 using MVC4 and the VS2012-era Web API version.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable CORS on a single controller simply by adding the appropriate headers:

```
// allow the browser to send cross-origin requests
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://foo.com");

// optional: allow the browser to send cookies with the request
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

No need for MVC 5 or new packages.